# Apple ID Password email address is inccorrect but store email address IS correct after restoring iPhone 4S

Tags: itunes

So weird thing happened last night.  I was updating the iOS to my iPhone 4S when the cord accidentally got jerked out of the phone.  I had to reset the phone and restore from back-up.  Now when I try to update the apps the window pops up asking for my password but weird thing.....the email address that it show is NOT my email address.  When I go into my phone setting AND the Apple Store it shows my Apple ID email correct.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it display an old emailaddress of yours? Or just something weird?

Comment: So you don't even recognize the email?

Answer (score 1):

If an app was installed by someone else (say, a friend or family member) using their Apple ID, you will be required to type in that Apple ID's password to reauthorize the app to your device now that it has been wiped & restored.

If it is a free app it is asking you to authorize, you can also remove the app and re-download through the App Store using your own Apple ID account.